# How Prettier works In JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

To use HTTPS, I uncomment the server.port:433 section in the application-prod-yml file and comment out the server.port:8080 section based on [the document](https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#https-support). After the change, I get "All collection items must start at the same column" when I try to push the change to the Git server. My Idea IDE shows no other changes. I run

```
./mvnw verify
```

without any error.

Why does the error occur.

Comment: Did you look at the git hooks that use husky?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for your input. I was looking into the prettier and will try to edit some related items in the package.json file. I have seen Husky somewhere, but don't know what it is about, nor about hooks. I will have a look. We use GitLab, but not GitHub.

Comment: These are hooks that are run by git client so it does not matter whether you use gitlab or github.

Comment: I have a look at the package.json file, but can't see how hook, lint, and prettier work together. Still can't figure why the error occurs after the server configure change.